# Approximation of 3d graph function

Tags: functions

For a better figure I need to re-plot the following 3d graph:

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-28191525/graph.jpg.html

Could you tell me the rough function of it? Just ignore the red circle. I will try to plot it with Mac 'Grapher' unless you know a better free tool for that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look only at the shape, not the scale or position of the graph. These can later be adjusted by choosing the range of the coordinates.

the front right side seems to be a parabola opening to the bottom so something like $z = -y^2$

the shape on the right back wall is also a parabola (see the grid)  but opening to the right $z = -\sqrt{x}$.

the surface seems to be the product of the two, avoiding double negative and shifting it up leads to
$$z=1-y^2\sqrt{x}$$

Comment: Thank you very much so far! Using MATLAB I am getting the result as denoted by this link: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-28241286/MATLAB_v1.png.html ->                                                                                              >> x=[0:1:20];
>> y=[0:1:20];
>> [xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
>> zz=1-yy.^2*sqrt(xx);
>> figure
>> surf(xx,yy,zz); But how can I adjust the MATLAB code to get the required graph of the first link?

Comment: try x from 0 to 1 and y from -1 to 1. maybe you can also switch x and y to get the same orientation.